# Alternatives to using remote-exec in terraform vmware

Tags: terraform, vmware, bare-metal-server, terraform-provider-vsphere

I'm provisioning servers in a bare metal environment that uses vmware to virtualize the machines.
In this scenario I need to use alternatives in the use of remote-exec, this happens because I have restrictions.
What is the suggestion for me to be able to install programs inside the vm that is being provisioned?

I want to run replace this code:

```
###exemplo de comando
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "id",
      "uname -a",
      "cat /etc/os-release",
      "echo \"machine-id is $(cat /etc/machine-id)\"",
      "lsblk -x KNAME -o KNAME,SIZE,TRAN,SUBSYSTEMS,FSTYPE,UUID,LABEL,MODEL,SERIAL",
      "mount | grep ^/dev",
      "df -h",
    ]
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      user = "vagrant"
      host = self.default_ip_address
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you able to share what the restrictions are? Is it just SSH, all inbound connections, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

May be this [ssh_resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/loafoe/ssh/latest/docs/resources/resource) provider?

```
resource "ssh_resource" "init" {
  host              = self.default_ip_address
  user              = "vagrant"
  agent             = true
  # An ssh-agent with your SSH private keys should be running
  # Use 'private_key' to set the SSH key otherwise

  timeout = "5m"

  commands = [
    "id",
    "uname -a",
    "cat /etc/os-release",
    "echo \"machine-id is $(cat /etc/machine-id)\"",
    "lsblk -x KNAME -o KNAME,SIZE,TRAN,SUBSYSTEMS,FSTYPE,UUID,LABEL,MODEL,SERIAL",
    "mount | grep ^/dev",
    "df -h"
  ]
}
```

To let you know this is not a plugin coming from Hashicorp but from a third-party source.